# Update state of a rendered component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I have imported a component to render on my page. I pass data to the component and it renders differently depending on what is selected. I am having trouble updating the state of the imported component in the function below

```
//imported component
import TestComponent from './test'

onFunctionClicked = mT => () => {
this.setState({
  dataType2: dType2
});

var dType1 = this.state.dataType1;

ReactDOM.render(  <TestComponent dataType1={dType1} dataType2={mT}/> ,  document.getElementById('displayTestComponent '));
};  

<div className="displayTariffsCss" id="displayTariffs" />                         
                          
                    
<input onClick={this.onFunctionClicked('someData')} checked={this.state.dataType2 === 'someData' ? true : false} " type="radio" />
```

the function `onFunctionClicked` is called in a few different places and the datatypes changed depending on what is click but once the first one is clicked i cannot update the state when another is clicked. Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: need some more detail about code. `dType2` declaration and how you change the value of `dType2`?

Comment: Sorry I included the input sectionm thanks for getting back

Comment: there's quite a few issues with this code. `ReactDOM.render` shouldn't live inside a function. you need to bind the onClick function, at the bottom it'll be called when the component mounts rather than onClick. also onClick on an input seems an odd thing to do